# Breakpoint Pair not functioning as expected

Tags: breakpoint-sass

I've just installed Breakpoint via bower and I'm using a sample right from the wiki: https://github.com/Team-Sass/breakpoint/wiki/Basic-Media-Queries

```
$pair: 456px 794px;

#foo {
  @include breakpoint($pair) {
    content: 'Paired Media Query';
  }
}
```

I should see this output:

```
@media (min-width: 456px) and (max-width: 794px) {
  #foo {
    content: 'Paired Media Query';
  }
}
```

Instead, I see this:

```
@media (min-width: 456px), (min-width: 794px) {
  #foo {
    content: 'Paired Media Query';
  }
```

}

Could anyone help me resolve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add this line to my gruntfile.js > compass > options >

```
require: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/compass-breakpoint/lib/breakpoint',
```